# Why does assault sideline "imminent fear of harm in the future", and require merely "fear of imminent harm"?

Tags: england-and-wales, assault

[*Concentrate Criminal Law* (2020 7 edn)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Criminal-Law-Concentrate-Revision-Study-dp-0198854986/dp/0198854986/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) pp 52-53.

> The most common mistakes students make when explaining or applying the law on technical
> assault are:

> - confusing fear with apprehension (see ‘The main issues’, above);

> - confusing an immediate apprehension with an apprehension of immediate harm, so:
>
> – if V says ‘I now expect to be hit tomorrow’, there is no technical assault (even if V is very afraid of the future harm), but

> – if V says ‘I expect now to be hit now, but I am not afraid’, the *actus reus* of a technical assault is satisfied. Do not forget to consider if D satisfies the mens rea too;

> – if V says ‘I am not sure when I will be hit: it may be tomorrow or it might be now’ that can be an assault according to *Constanza* [1997] because the victim fears they might be hit in the immediate future.

Herring, [*Criminal Law: Text, Cases, and Materials* (8 edn, 2018)](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/criminal-law-9780198811817?cc=ca&lang=en&). p. 75

> ### What does ‘imminent’ mean?

> The victim’s apprehension must be of imminent harm. It is well established that a threat to be
> violent in the distant future (e.g. ‘I will beat you up next week’) is not an assault.<sup>13</sup> But what
> about a threat to cause violence in the near future? Lord Steyn in Ireland indicated that a fear of
> violence ‘within a minute or two’ might be sufficient to constitute an assault.<sup>14</sup> This leaves open
> the question of exactly where the line is to be drawn: is fear of violence in ten minutes enough,
> an hour, a day? We can know only when we have further guidance from the courts.

> ...

[image]

> ...

> <sup>13</sup> But there are some specific offences that relate to threats to harm in the future, e.g. there is an offence
> of threatening to kill in the Offences Against the Person Act 1861, s. 16.
> <sup>14</sup> See also *Smith v Superintendent of Woking Police Station* (1983) 76 Cr App R 234.

I refer to red underlines in blue box.

1. Why "not enough to show that as a result of the defendant's actions[,] the victim immediately feared that he or she might be harmed a long in the future"?
2. "In other words", why "imminent fear of harm in the future" not assault?
   I can't distinguish between "fear of imminent harm" (green) v. "imminent fear of harm in the future" (red).

Comment: wdym why? the lawmakers wanted it this way

Comment: @MaxB why did the lawmakers want it this way? i think i'm asking about Legislative Intent.

Comment: I suppose it's because otherwise, you have a chance to call the cops and let them handle it. So intimidation is a lesser crime than assault

Answer (score 5):

Assault is defined as "putting someone in fear of imminent harm".

Imminent means "about to happen".

- "fear of imminent harm" means the harm is about to happen (very soon)
- "fear of harm in the future" means the harm might happen later
- "imminent fear of harm in the future" is probably a usage mistake, but might technically happen if you are about to feel the fear.

Comment: thanks. did you answer my questions 1 and 2 please? i think you answered just part of question 2.